# Tailwind colors based on dark mode

Tags: tailwind-css

Is there any way to define different colors in the tailwind config so that the dark mode are applied without the `dark` selector?

Currently I have an object like:

```
const colors = {
 light: {
    red: {
     100: "#880808",
    ...
    }
  },
 dark: {
    red: {
     100: "red",
    ...
    }
  },

}
```

I'd **like** to just use `red-100` and have the color be mapped automatically (just via `bg-red-100`) without having to specify `bg-red-100 dark:bg-red-dark-100`

Comment: I had the same question but after some research and without any normal results I just started to use bg-red-100 dark:bg-red-dark-100. Looks like it isn't a problem for the other TW geeks so they just use the same approach as well

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can define your colors in your CSS file like this :

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer base {

  :root {
    --color-primary: 247 147 34;
    --color-text: 33 33 33;
    --color-success: 0 200 81;
    --color-info: 51 181 229;
    --color-warn: 255 187 51;
    --color-error: 254 78 78;
  }

  :root[class~="dark"] {
    --color-primary: 247 147 34;
    --color-text: 33 33 33;
    --color-success: 0 200 81;
    --color-info: 51 181 229;
    --color-warn: 255 187 51;
    --color-error: 254 78 78;
  }
}
```

and then use this config in your `tailwind.config.js`:

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  darkMode: "class",
  theme: {
    colors: {
      primary: "rgb(var(--color-primary) / <alpha-value>)",
      text: "rgb(var(--color-text) / <alpha-value>)",
      success: "rgb(var(--color-success) / <alpha-value>)",
      info: "rgb(var(--color-info) / <alpha-value>)",
      warn: "rgb(var(--color-warn) / <alpha-value>)",
      error: "rgb(var(--color-error) / <alpha-value>)",
      transparent: "transparent",
      current: "currentColor",
    },
}
```

now if you set the dark class on your document root colors changed automatically

Comment: Don't forget to add the `<alpha-value>` to your theme otherwise you will loose support for tailwinds opacity classes. `primary: "rgb(var(--color-primary) / <alpha-value>)"`. You can view more information in the tailwind documentation (https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors)

Comment: :root[class="dark"]  colors is not being considered when dark is present in the class.

Comment: @ShashiKiran so, do you mean this solution doesn't work?

Comment: Just in case someone finds it easier to read, in this context the CSS selector `:root[class~="dark"]` is the same as the CSS selector `html.dark`.

Comment: Tailwind allows us to define data-* attributes to set dark mode, not just classes. For example, I use data-mode="dark", so I thought it's a simpler way to do this. @cprcrack

Comment: I wonder why this isn't supported by default...

Answer (score 6):

[Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tw-colors) is a tailwind plugin ([tw-colors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tw-colors)) that does exactly what you need.

```
   const { createThemes } = require('tw-colors');

   module.exports = {
      // ...your tailwind config
      plugins: [
         createThemes({
            'light': { 
               'red': {
                  '100': '#880808',
                  '200': '...',
               }
            },
            'dark': { 
               'red': {
                  '100': 'red',
                  '200': '...',
               }
            },
         })
      ],
   };
```

Apply the theme on a parent element

```
<div class={someCondition ? 'theme-light' : 'theme-dark'}>  
  ...
</div>
```

You can use your colors as usual.

```
<button class='bg-red-100'>...</div>
```

If `theme-light` is applied on a parent element, the background-color will be `#880808`, if `theme-dark` is applied it will be `red`

Answer (score 2):

One trick that you can make use of is by [extracting as components](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#adding-component-classes).

In your tailwind stylesheet

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer components {
  .red-bg {
    @apply bg-red-100 dark:bg-red-dark-100;
  }
}
```

Then you can use it as

```
<div class="red-bg"></div>
```

and it work as intended. However, it would be a best practice to use other approaches in [re-using the styles](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/reusing-styles) since it would be inconvenient to extend this trick to all colors used in your project.